# Javascript http server: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

I recently attempted to install an SSL certificate to my server. The certificate files (privkey.pem, fullchain.pem) are in the root directory of the application. When I run the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var helmet = require('helmet');
var db = require('./server/database.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var ssl = require('ssl-root-cas');

'use strict';
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();

// default for all https requests
// (whether using https directly, request, or another module)
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;

app.use(helmet()); 

var options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'ascii'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'ascii')
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var serv = require('https').createServer(options, app);
```

The server runs with no errors. The "Server is listening on port 80" Confirmation I added shows, and the certificate appears to not cause any direct issues. However when I attempt to connect to the domain(using https://) Chrome responds with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. When connecting to the domain via http, Chrome responds with the same message. I am using SocketIO, which is initialized later in the code, I have not found any connection between my issue and SocketIO's functions. What is causing the inability to connect?

Comment: Was it working before you added the certificate?

Comment: Yes, only after I added support for https did it stop working.

Comment: Are you able to look at the logs?

Comment: These logs would be located where? I have FTP and SSH access to the server.

Comment: The `https` prefix in the URL makes your browser connecting to port 443 and not to 80. It is not sufficient, that your server listens on port 80.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the server to listen on 443 worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The https request is sent over port 443 rather than 80. The following code worked without issues:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var helmet = require('helmet');
var db = require('./server/database.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var ssl = require('ssl-root-cas');

'use strict';
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();

// default for all https requests
// (whether using https directly, request, or another module)
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;

app.use(helmet()); 

var options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'ascii'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'ascii')
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var serv = require('https').createServer(options, app);
//var serv = require('https').Server(app); //DEBUG ONLY
```